# Can I put LOG4J jar at server level and still manage to use LOG4J.XML of individual War files

Tags: java, log4j, overwrite, appender

Can I put LOG4J jar at server level and still manage to use LOG4J.XML ofindividual War files ?

I have a problem here. I know the way to get around this problem is to package LOG4J jar in my own EAR or WAR file. But is there a way to put my LOG4J jar in the server level classpath, and have each application follow its own log4j.xml. In this case the LOG4J is getting initialized once with the log4j.xml of the first invoked application and applies the same properties for all the applications.It does not bother to look for the LOG4J.XML of the other applications.

You help is really appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you want to do so? Do you need separate logging level for each? Clarify please.

Comment: Because, I may want to have the 1st application write the logging to app1.log, and the 2nd application write the logging to app2.log. I might need a custom appender for one application and do not need the custom appender for another application. Logging level could be different as well. Simply i need totally different logging for both the applications.